# How to create a list only with a unique element using this list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
a =  [['Rostock', 'Lubeck'], ['Rostock', 'Hamburg'], ['Rostock', 'Bremen'], ['Rostock', 'Hannover']]
```

I want to create list only with unique element:

```
result = ['Rostock', 'Lubeck', 'Hamburg', 'Bremen', 'Hannover']
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming order matters

```
>>> a =  [['Rostock', 'Lubeck'], ['Rostock', 'Hamburg'], ['Rostock', 'Bremen'], ['Rostock', 'Hannover']]
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(y for x in a for y in x))
['Rostock', 'Lubeck', 'Hamburg', 'Bremen', 'Hannover']
```

or equivalently:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(a)))
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Order does matter. I will accept your answer whenever I can.

Comment: Beautiful use of an `OrderedDict` - I'd personally use `chain.from_iterable`, but apart from that - exactly what I'd use :)

Answer (score 1):

If order doesn't matter - use set:

```
a =  [['Rostock', 'Lubeck'], ['Rostock', 'Hamburg'], ['Rostock', 'Bremen'], ['Rostock', 'Hannover']]
print list(set(y for x in a for y in x))  # prints ['Rostock', 'Hannover', 'Bremen', 'Lubeck', 'Hamburg']
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this more readable:

```
a =  [['Rostock', 'Lubeck'], ['Rostock', 'Hamburg'], ['Rostock', 'Bremen'], ['Rostock', 'Hannover']]

result = []

for x in a:
    for y in x:
        if y not in result:
            result.append(y)
```

This is the output:

```
>>> print(result)
['Rostock', 'Lubeck', 'Hamburg', 'Bremen', 'Hannover']
```